# Как запретить двигать консоль

Tags: c#, winapi, консоль

Какими средствами `WinAPI` можно заблокировать перемещение окна консоли?

Comment: Зачем вам это понадобилось?

Comment: @tutankhamun,Хочу освоить  некоторые навыки при работе с консолями, для удобства.

Comment: Найти окно консоли, встроить хук, реагировать на `WM_MOVE` или как оно там.

Comment: Хм, кажется, это не так просто. Вы не можете засабклассить консольное окно, т. к. оно бежит не в вашем процессе, а принадлежит системному процессу CSRSS. Вы не можете сделать туда хук, т. к. вы не являетесь DLL, и, кажется, CSRSS бежит с повышенными правами, так что это не получилось бы даже будь вы нативной DLL. То есть по существу надежды мало :( Вот связанные ответы: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13438939/276994, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11176952/276994.

Comment: @VladD, Буду знать =) Спасибо за наводку.

Comment: @ArteS: Но с другой стороны, возможно, вы сможете просто стилизовать обычное окно «под консоль» (чёрный фон, моноширинный шрифт). Со своим окном можно вытворять всё, что угодно.

Comment: @VladD, Обязательно узнаю в отдельной теме =). Пока мне удалось реализовать вызов в центральной области рабочего стола, и отключить кнопки закрыть/свернуть/развернуть :D Будим учиться!